# Where to run `$ php vendors install` from?

Tags: symfony

I am new to Symfony, and there are many command lines need to be run, but I did not know where to run those commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the directory where you installed Symfony. There shold be some subdirectories: `app`, `src`, `bin`, `vendors`... And the command you should run is `php bin/vendors install`.

Notice that this command is for Symfony 2.0.x. If you installed the latest symfony version (2.1.x) you should not use this command and use Composer instead.